# how to show a panel node only to authenticated users?

Tags: 7, users, panels

i am using panel nodes to display profile pages such as my profile page on facebook . i have created a menu link for it . When i logout my profile link still shows. I want that only the logged in user should see the my profile link.

Comment: Cross Posting not allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511554/how-to-show-a-panel-node-only-to-authenticated-users

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module should help You because it gives You ability to grant access to content type (panel) or - after select "*Enable per content node access control settings* " option - to single node.